# What is equivalent function of excel "fdist" function in R?

Tags: r, excel

I am studying R, but found several difficulty to find suitable functions.

I want to calculate f-distribution to do ANOVA, with this situation :

```
Regression F = 10.97
Regression df = 2
Residual df = 23
```

`fdist(10.97;2;23)` in excel, it gives me "**0.00045**", however, **df(10.97,2,23)** in R, the result is "**0.0002310386**"

I also calculate it with TI-stat and its result is $4.52 x 10^{-4}$

Could you let me know what should I do to get same result by using R?

Comment: =FDIST(10.97,2,23)/2=> 0.00023

Comment: And if you multiply result from R by 2, you get 0.00046. Why do you think it's that? :)

Comment: Thanks! But I still do not understand why should I multiply it by 2 to become same result with excel. Could you let me know the reason? I also calculate it with TI-stat calculator and its result is 4.52 x 10^{-4} not 0.00046 (=df(10.97,2,23)*2) in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the distribution function and not the density:

```
pf(10.97,2,23, lower.tail=FALSE)
#[1] 0.0004514294
```

Answer (score 2):

In Office 2013 the help page for `FDIST` states:

> This function has been replaced with one or more new functions that
>   may provide improved accuracy and whose names better reflect their
>   usage.
>   [...]
>   For more information about the new functions, see F.DIST function and
>   F.DIST.RT function.

Here's R's result displayed to more decimal places:

```
format(df(10.97,2,23), digits = 15)
## [1] "0.000231038629222813"
```

In Excel, you need to pass a `cumulative = FALSE` argument to get the same answer:

```
=F.DIST(10.97,2,23, FALSE)
0.000231038629222813
```

For comparison, `cumulative = TRUE` returns the same a R's `pf` function.

```
format(pf(10.97,2,23), digits = 15)
## [1] "0.999548570608814"

=F.DIST(10.97,2,23, TRUE)
0.999548570608814
```

`F.DIST.RT` is the right tailed equivalent distribution, which oddly, only gives you the cumulative form.

```
=F.DIST.RT(10.97,2,23)
0.000451429391185792
```

(Oh, this is the same as `FDIST`!)

As Roland pointed out, it corresponds to:

```
format(pf(10.97,2,23, lower.tail = FALSE), digits = 15)
## [1] "0.000451429391185792"
```